# How is the sound converted to matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, audio, matrix

I am using the `audioread(filename,y,Fs)` function of Matlab and it converts an audio file to a matrix. I want to know how is each value of that matrix generated. Is it possible to produce a specific sound like the sound of a guitar by giving your own values to the matrix and then sounding it using the `sound()` function?

Comment: how did you converts an audio file to a matrix ?

Comment: using the audioread(filename,y,Fs) function of Matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `audioread` doesn't generate any values, it just reads audio samples stored in a file. If you want to generate the sound of a guitar, you need to look into sound synthesis, such as the [Karplus-Strong method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karplus%E2%80%93Strong_string_synthesis).

Comment: actually i want to know how it actually reads audio samples or what does it reads from the audio file. What do you mean by samples?

Comment: would you please elaborate a little more? @Matt

Comment: @Jordan: *Samples* are values taken from the signal (such as a microphone signal). These samples are taken at regular intervals, such that the originally analog signal is represented is sufficient detail. These sampled signal values can be stored in a file and they are read and copied to a data matrix by the function `audioread` If you don't know about sampling, start by reading [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28signal_processing%29).

Comment: Ok i will read it. Thanks i really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is definitely possible to produce the specific sound like guitar. but the point is do we know the values(matrix values) which will produce that specific sound.

Regarding " how is each value of that matrix generated" , those are generated by the transducer's(microphone) action on sound waves.When you read a file using audioread, you are just able to see those values in matrix form.

Comment: Actually the first point you raised is my question! How to calculate the values(matrix values) which will produce a specific sound. 
Secondly I know that when I read a file using audioread, I am able to see those values in matrix form but i need to know how is this function calculating these values.

Comment: @Jordan Oh ! thanks for your clarification.I think Matt L. answered it properly and clearly now.